# Question about Thrust; am I correct?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science

Basically, here's what I understand about Thrust:

Thrust is a force. You get it by doing $v\times\frac{dM}{dT}$. Pretty basic, because that's the formula you're given. However, because I'm trying to remember this, I sort of derived it.

$\Sigma \vec F=\frac{d\vec p}{dt}$, $p$ being momentum.

$\vec p=M\vec v$

However, because in thrust problems mass is not constant but velocity is,

$\frac{d\vec p}{dt} = \frac{dM}{dt}\times \vec v$

$\Sigma \vec F=\frac{d\vec p}{dt}$

Thus,

$\Sigma \vec F=v\times\frac{dM}{dT}$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best way to think about this is to say that

$$p = mv\\
F=\frac{dp}{dt}=m\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{dm}{dt}$$

(Using the usual product rule for differentiation - thanks @ja72 for the suggestion). If velocity is constant the first term vanishes and your result follows.

Comment: The above is an application of the product rule we learned in calculus.

Comment: @ja72  good point to clarify - I edited that into my answer.